# Tinkerpop3 Gremlin Traversal Error

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a graph with the following structure:

```
|-ProductFit
|-|-Part
|-|-App
|-|-|-ProductID
|-|-|-ProductModelID
|-|-|-ProductYearID

|-ProductID
|-|-ProductName
|-|-ProductModelID
|-|-ProductYearID

|-ProductModelID
|-|-ProductModelName

|-ProductYearID
|-|-ProductYear
```

where ProductFit is my first independent vertex and ProductID, ProductModelID and ProductYearID as my connected vertices.

Now, there are some fields of ProductID's in ProductFit having wrong values for which I need to get values from other vertex of ProductID.

Here is my query:

```
g.V().has('ProductFit','Part','PA01').properties('App')
.valueMap('ProductID','ProductModelID','ProductYearID')
.choose(values('ProductModelID'))
.option(PM01, g.V().has('ProductFit','Part','PA01').properties('App').values('ProductModelID'))
.option(PM02, g.V().has('ProductID','ProductModelID','PM01'))
.values('ProductModelID')
```

But this is giving me this error:

```
java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element
```

Is it that I can't go from one vertex to other during traversal or is there some problem in query? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `choose()` is using `values()` which is not meant to pick values out of a `Map`. It is meant to be used with an `Element`. I get the same error on The Crew toy graph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createTheCrew()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:14]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:14], standard]
gremlin> g.V().properties('location').valueMap().choose(values('startTime')).option(2004,constant(1)).option(none,constant(2))
java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]n
```

You should instead use `select`:

```
gremlin> g.V().properties('location').valueMap().choose(select('startTime')).option(2004,constant(1)).option(none,constant(2))
==>2
==>2
==>1
...
==>2
```